# I have a question about mantra, and Vajrayana Buddhism?

Tags: vajrayana, mantra

My question is this is the mantra Om Ah Hum Benza Guru Padma Siddhi Hum a Vajrayana mantra? Can I chant it? I am asking because, I’m wondering why I’ve had the company of hallucinations? Will the mental health problems be permanent, until I see a Lama to give me my refuge vows?

Answer (score 1):

If reciting a mantra is causing you to hallucinate, I would recommend immediately stopping that practice.

Formal refuge under a Vajrayāna guru cannot cure mental illness. It can't even cure depression. The Buddhadharma isn't about making one's life more comfortable (not claiming you said so).

I don't know anything in-depth about the Vajraguru mantra (that is the name of the mantra you inquired about). Because it is Guru Padmasaṃbhava's mantra, you chanting it without initiation is likely a mishandling of the mantra according to the traditions that use that mantra.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I am feeling fine but I did start to hear things. But I remember now I heard things here and there all the time. Sorry if I raise concern. I was just scared it could possibly have to do with the mantra. Because I read if you practice Vajrayana Buddhism it can cause you mental health problems, if your not initiated by a lama and you take your vows first. Sorry but thank you for your knowledge.

Comment: It doesn't "cause" mental health problems. If you already have them, then certain practices have the risk of leavening them.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: If one takes a measured approach, mental health can indeed be cured. The whole principles of Buddhist logic pivots on the notion that we are suffering from mental delusions; we are neurotic and that neurosis is just a stones throw away from psychosis - for everyone!. Therefore, it figures that, for some, they will venture into the area of psychosis. When this happens, the general response is to somehow refute it, deny it, and call it wrong. This isn't helpful. Any form of practice that erodes your routine defense mechanisms, can unearth various psychiatric symptoms.